# How does a sqlalchemy object get detached?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have code structured something like this:

```
project
--app
----utils
------util.py
----__init__.py
----models.py
--tests
----__init__.py
```

Within tests/__init__.py I have code that initializes the application (flask if that matters) and database session by importing it all from app/__init__.py.  I can create an instances of models, query, and access backrefs fine within tests/__init__.py.  Code of the following form works fine:

```
objs = SomeModel.query.all()
for o in objs:
    o.backref
```

However, if I do something like:

```
from utils.util import some_function
objs = SomeModel.query.all()
for o in objs:
    some_function(o)
```

where some_function just accesses a backref

```
def some_function(obj):
    obj.backref
```

I get an error like `DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <SomeModel at 0x2c1fe10> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'backref' cannot proceed`

Reading the sqlalchemy docs suggests that I need to re-associate the object to a database sesssion.  I did that and it looks like it works (i.e. running the function doesn't fail with the previous error):

```
import db_session
def some_function(obj):
    db_session.add(obj)
    obj.backref
```

So when exactly does an object get detached?  It seems like just passing the object to a function in another module detaches it from a session. Does the object not know about the sqlalchemy session it is associated with?  I'm trying to avoid doing `db_session.add(obj)` which seems like a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: I can't get the same result on similar code. Can you provide minimal code that reproduces the same error error you're having?

Comment: The some_function function is a synchronous celery task.  Sorry for not including that.  I'll update the question further when I do reproduce it with minimal code.

Answer (score 16):

I came across this while working on my own [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35296646/1118357) about attribute expiration & instance detachment. [univerio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341730/univerio) gave a me a great answer, and from what I've been learning, I might be able to shed some light on your question.

In my case I was creating, committing or rolling back, and then closing a `Session` all within the scope of a single `with...as...` clause, then trying to access the instance I saved (the `obj` in your example) immediately afterward *but outside the scope of that `with` clause*. What happened was the `Session` was closed before I tried to reference the saved object. *By default in SQLAlchemy, persisted attributes/objects cannot be accessed without an **active** `Session`, unless explicitly told to allow it*. This is to "protect" code from accidentally or unknowingly using outdated/incorrect data, by forcing the application to query/retrieve the *updated* data first, which requires an associated `Session`. So in my case, leaving the `Session` open after committing meant the object could use that `Session` to query the database in case the record had been modified since it was first written.

In your case, the `Session` being used to get the objects via `objs = SomeModel.query.all()` is being closed or disconnected after the query but before `obj.backref` is called (though I'm not sure how; I don't know what `SomeModel` is, exactly, I'm assuming is a construct from Flask which incorporates a `Session` in its background). So `obj` no longer has a connection to the database and thus is "detached". By adding it to `db_session` you allow `obj` to reestablish connectivity to its source database, through which it can query to check for updated attributes, and so it's no longer detached.

Finally, it's worth mentioning that the `DetachedInstanceError` can be avoided by specifying the original `Session` to which `obj` was associated not to *expire* attributes automatically. By not *expiring* the `obj`, the error wouldn't be thrown, *but `obj` would still be **detached***, meaning when you called `obj.backref` the returned value may be incorrect/outdated. You asked about detaching in your question, but expiration is a related, but not identical, concept.

*Aside -- how to set the `obj` not to expire:* Either at the `Session`'s initialization

```
my_session = sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=False
```

the `sessionmaker`'s initialization

```
my_sessionmaker = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=False)
```

or even after the `Session` is already instantiated

```
my_session.expire_on_commit = False
```

Comment: Great answer. Session.add(detachedInstance) helped me get rid of these annoying mistakes in my Flask py.test run. I would just like to point out that defining sessionmaker with expire_on_commit=False, although fine at first sight, does introduce side effects on database persistence that, in my case, resulted in other errors that were much more difficult to fix. For instance, the same code would commit twice the same instance that had a unique constraint set on it with expire_on_commit=False.

Comment: Thanks, the last suggestion in particular was very useful as I did not use `sessionmaker` in my code. This is the only answer I've seen that ever listed this method, not even the docs mentioned it. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while trying to implement an upsert operation:

```
objs = [SomeModel(id=1, value=2), SomeModel(id=2, value=4)]

for obj in objs:
    fltr_obj = session.query(SomeModel).where(SomeModel.id == obj.id)
    if fltr_obj.first() is None:
        # add if the object does not exist
        session.add(fltr)
    else:
        # update if the object exists
        fltr_obj.update({"id": obj.id, "value": obj.value})

session.commit()
```

and I got `detachedInstanceError`. I have fixed this error by replacing the latter with

```
objs = [SomeModel(id=1, value=2), SomeModel(id=2, value=4)]
for obj in objs:
    session.merge(obj)

session.commit()
```